# Grub detects wrong Linux distro

Tags: linux, boot, grub, linux-mint

**DESCRIPTION:** I dual-boot Linux Mint 18 (up to date) with Cinnamon, and Windows 10 using Grub bootloader. This week I had some updates come through Mint's update manager, and I believe one was a Linux kernel update. Anyhow, last night (3/10/2017) I did a restart so I could boot into Windows and play some Steam games, and when Grub came up, instead of saying "Linux Mint 18....." It just said "Ubuntu", and another option on the list that used to say "Linux Mint 18...." also said "Ubuntu". I know that Mint is an offshoot of Ubuntu, so perhaps this is a harmless issue, but I'm quite concerned about trying to boot into Mint again.

**QUESTIONS:** What caused Grub to detect the wrong Linux? Will something very, very bad happen if I do another restart and try to boot into Mint, while Grub just shows "Ubuntu"? How do I fix this?

I'm quite new to Linux, having only recently fallen in love with it, so please try to be super clear with everything.

Comment: This has something to do with the recent updates and you chose to overwrite (replace) the existing configuration file, in general never do that... I just opened grub-customerizer and everything was still there so I saved it and it was back to saying Linux Mint on the next boot. Otherwise it is purely cosmetic and should not effect actual use of the system. The next kernel update should fix it as well.

Comment: @acejavelin Like I said, I'm new to Linux stuff and just scraping the surface in terms of knowing and doing stuff. Nearly deleted my PATH variable, took 40 minutes to figure out how to upgrade firefox, etc. I just figured the guys doing updates would know what they were doing, and to trust whatever they sent out. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @acejavelin If you feel confident in your answer, make it an answer and I'll upvote and select it in 36-48 hours, pending other answers and me actually trying to boot into Mint. I think the "don't overwrite stuff" tip would be a valuable answer to have pop up on this site for noobs like me.